# How to restore database after Stellar testnet reset?

Tags: stellar-core, testnet, stellar-website

I have read their post reset maintenance here:

https://github.com/stellar/packages#testnet-reset

can we still use test account in testnet after reset or do we always have to create new one?

if we can restore data on in DB do I only have to dump and restore DB before initialize  `#sudo stellar-horizon-cmd db init`

`#sudo systemctl stop stellar-horizon
 [dump here]
 #sudo -u stellar psql -c 'DROP DATABASE horizon'
 #sudo -u stellar psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE horizon'
 [restore here]
 #sudo stellar-horizon-cmd db init
 #sudo systemctl start stellar-horizon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a complete reset, starting over with a brand new ledger from zero. Your dump/backup will not be consistent with the new network state by any means and it won't work at all.

You have to create new test accounts and it is best practice to automate that.

Other than that you may run your own private testnet or standalone node and thus be independent of public testnet resets.